# Submission not confirmed html php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an form with submit button as follows in html :-

```
  <div style="display: flex;">
         <form name="myform"method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:left;">
                <div id="log_err"> <strong><?php if(isset($logerror)) { echo $logerror; } else { $dn = 'dn'; } ?></strong> </div>   
                    <p><label style="float: left;">Price:</label><input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="username" id="box1" oninput="calculate()"><label style="float: right;">: BTC</label><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
                     <br><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="result"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total BTC:</label>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <input type="hidden" id="myform" value="1"/>
                        <br><span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="ordersell" onclick="myform.submit()">SELL</span></p>
                    </td>

            </form>
            <form name="yourform"method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:right;">
                    <p><label style="float: left;">Price:</label><input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="username" id="box3" oninput="calculate()"><label style="float: right;">: BTC</label><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box4" oninput="calculate()">
                     <br><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="resul"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total BTC:</label>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <input type="hidden" id="yourform" value="1"/>
                        <br>
                        <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="orderbuy" onclick="yourform.submit()">BUY</span></p>
                    </td>

            </form>
            </div>
```

And to check whether user clicked 'SELL' button i do in php :-

```
  if($_POST['myform']){
 echo 'yes'; 
 }
 else {
  echo 'no';
 }
```

I am always getting no after clicking button, is there anything wrong that I haved coded in the html or php part? Help is appreciated.. I just want to get the part for php

```
 if($_POST['?']) {...
```

Remember there are two forms in the page with each having name and hidden input id.

Comment: forms don't usually need name attributes or relying on POST to check it with. You need to check the inputs. The named attribute on the form suggests using JS; so are you?

Comment: why are you using two forms here? I've no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Missing space in `<form name="myform"method="post"` and `<form name="yourform"method="post"`. That's probably why you don't get any `$_POST` vars.

Comment: Also, your `<input type="hidden"`s needs a `name` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="myform" value="1"/>
```

Change id attribute to name

```
<input type="hidden" name="myform" value="1">
```

And there's a missing space in form tag